# ERROR ITMS-90725: "This app was built with the iOS 12.1 SDK. New apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later."

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, phonegap

I use build phonegap for build IOS app....I genarated .ipa file with last version of phonegap build but when I try yo upload .ipa file to apple store it give that error

ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 12.1 SDK. New apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later."

what should I do?

Comment: I used monaca but now it give UIWEBVIEW error.Is this Apple is enemy of developers? 
  .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626596/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-new-apps-that-use-uiwebview-are-no-longer-acc

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a service which does support the latest version of XCode (currently 11.6), like [VoltBuilder](https://volt.build), Ionic or Monaca. It doesn't look like PhoneGap is ever going to be updated.

Disclosure: I'm one of the developers of VoltBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to build on PhoneGap Build Cloud targeting iOS 13, since it requires cordova 6.0.0 and the lastest phonegap-cli avaiable is 9.0.0 which uses cordova 5.0.1 which targets iOS 12.1 and xcode 10.

You can build localy using cordova 6.0.0, if you don't have a mac you can try macincloud or another could solution as monaca and others.