# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, monaca

I use phonegal build but today i get this error when upload .ipa to apple store

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability

then I removed all cordova plugins in config.xml but still get some error.I researched and find monaca..In monaca configure option I choosed WKWebViewOnly but still i get some error..Here is my config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="com.demircode.bileteviniz" version="1.3.1">
  <name>BiletEviniz</name>
  <description>BiletEviniz</description>
  <author/>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  <preference name="Orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG"/>
  <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop"/>
  <preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000"/>
  <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="250"/>
  <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>
  <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false"/>
  <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray"/>
  <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0"/>
  <preference name="PageLength" value="0"/>
  <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page"/>
  <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated"/>
  <feature name="LocalStorage">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage"/>
  </feature>
  <preference name="UIWebViewDecelerationSpeed" value="normal"/>
  <preference name="monaca:AndroidIsPackageNameSeparate" value="false"/>
  <platform name="ios">
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
    <icon src="lobbe.png"/>
    <icon platform="ios" height="76" src="lobbe-76-76.png" width="76"/>
    <icon platform="ios" height="120" src="lobbe-120-120.png" width="120"/>
    <icon platform="ios" height="152" src="lobbe-152-152.png" width="152"/>
    <icon platform="ios" height="1024" src="lobbe-1024-1024.png" width="1024"/>
    <icon platform="ios" height="40" src="lobbe-40-40.png" width="40"/>
    <icon platform="ios" height="167" src="lobbe-167-167.png" width="167"/>
    <splash src="/res/ios/screen/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png"/>
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true"/>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine"/>
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine"/>
    </feature>
    <config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleLocalizations" target="*-Info.plist">
      <array>
        <string>tr</string>
        <string>en</string>
      </array>
    </config-file>
  </platform>
  <preference name="WindowsStorePublisherName" value="My Name"/>
  <preference name="WindowsStoreIdentityName" value="3e46a957-1e6e-2eb6-9380-b3b37c4dec02"/>
  <preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY" value="1,2"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
  <access origin="bileteviniz.com"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false"/>
</widget>
```

and this is package.json

```
 {
      "name": "monaca-template-minimum",
      "version": "2.0.7",
      "displayName": "Monaca Template Minimum",
      "dependencies": {
        "cordova-custom-config": "5.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
        "monaca-plugin-monaca-core": "3.3.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "monaca:preview": "npm run dev",
        "dev": "browser-sync start -s www/ --watch --port 8080 --ui-port 8081"
      },
      "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
          "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
          "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
          "cordova-custom-config": {},
          "monaca-plugin-monaca-core": {}
        }
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
        "cordova": "^9.0.0"
      }
    }
```

Comment: It isn't sufficient to just not use UIWebView, your code cannot have any reference at all.  You may need an updated version of the monaca plugin

Comment: I removed all plugins and add monaca you can see in config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your config.xml should look like this:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />

    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>

    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"/>
```

It's possible that one of your other plugins calls UIWebView. You may need to try leaving suspect plugins out until the problem goes away, then see if there is an updated version of the plugin.

(The config.xml code above is from the [VoltBuilder docs](https://volt.build/documentation/))